# Custom wp_list_pages() function

Tags: pages, excerpt, wp-list-pages

I have following code in my `.php` file:

```
$my_pages = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$my_id."&echo=0");
```

Then I create an `<ul>`

```
<ul>
  <?php echo $my_pages; ?>
</ul>
```

Problem is, that I would like to list a **title** in `<h2>` tag, and **excerpt** of the page on the text below. It´s possible to do that using `wp_list_pages`?

Comment: You should instead consider `WP_Query()`, but if you must use `wp_list_pages()`, you should check how to use it with a custom walker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. you will want to use `WP_Query()`

Here is the [Codex Article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) on that.

Example:

```
<?php

// Query All Pages
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=page' );

// The Loop
while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
    $my_query->the_post();
    echo '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2><p>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</p>';    
endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: A call to [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) after the loop would be beneficial.